# NextJS can't start app, getting unknow error

Tags: next.js

Randomly whenever nextjs feels like it, it produces an unknown error.

> [Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, readlink '\routes-manifest.json'] {
> type: 'Error',   errno: -4094,   code: 'UNKNOWN',   syscall:
> 'readlink',   path: '\routes-manifest.json'

it has happened twice to me and I don't know what causes this.

I also saw, for me to fix that you just have to delete the Next folder but when I do, I get a new error.

> *error page.tsx doesn't have a root layout. To fix this error, make
> sure every page has a root layout.*

but whenever I clone my repo and move all my new components it works just fine so I understand that I'm not doing anything wrong.

I think the issue is caused when trying to make a new fold/page while the app is running which then causes it to make a new layout page in that folder and break the whole app.

whenever running `npm run dev` I get an unknown error that happens in the next folder but once I delete the folder, I get a new error and have no idea how to fix it.

I would appreciate any type of help cause right now my only options are to keep cloning my repo and making a new file folder.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

delete .next folder  and start server npm run dev